# Karma failing with CI/CD in Github

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine, cicd

Karma is used to run unit test cases in one of my Angular applications. If you run it locally with the configuration shown below, there are no problems, however if you use CI/CD, you are now seeing the error message "No binary for Chrome browser on your platform. Please set the environment variable "CHROME_BIN"
Karma.conf.js:

```js
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false ,// leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
      jasmine: {
        random: false
      }
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: true,
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessCI: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--no-sandbox'
        ]
      }
    }
  });
};
```

And I attempted to set CHROME_BIN with Puppeteer as seen below after going through a few references, but I'm now encountering a different kind of problem. The problem with Puppeteer is that,

```js
`11 09 2023 10:49:24.520:ERROR [config]: Error in config file!
Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 116.0.5845.96). This can occur if either

you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. npm install) or
your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /opt/app-root/src/.cache/puppeteer).`
```

And this is the current Karma config file with Puppeteer.

```js
process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath()
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: ['karma-jasmine', 'karma-chrome-launcher',
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false ,// leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
      jasmine: {
        random: false
      }
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'ChromeHeadless', 'ChromeHeadlessCI'],
    singleRun: true,
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadless: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--headless',
          '--disable-gpu',
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--remote-debugging-port=9222',
        ]
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Can somebody help me understand whether there need to be any configuration adjustments made to the appropriate CI/CD in github?